# React Native Drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi there I am trying to implement a drawer navigation in React Native 
referring to [this example](http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/navigation/StackNavigationExample.html).

I have almost finished the coding but I am getting an error while adding the `contentComponent` attribute in drawer class (`HomeScreenRouter`). After removing it I am able to run it successfully and everything is working well but when I add the sidebar menu using `contentComponent` it throws an error. I need a custom design for my drawer.

[image: error-image]

Here is my code for the drawer:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen.js";
import MainScreenNavigator from "../DealScreen/mychat.js";
import Profiled from "../profilescreen/Profile.js";
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar.js";


import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
const HomeScreenRouter = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Chat: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
    Profile: { screen: Profiled },




  },

  {
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  });  
export default HomeScreenRouter;
```

Sidemenu :

```
import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Image, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Container, Content, Text, List, ListItem } from "native-base";

export default class SideBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const routes = ["Home", "Chat", "Profile"];
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: "https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/raw/react-navigation/img/drawer-cover.png"
            }}
            style={{
              height: 120,
              alignSelf: "stretch",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}>
            <Image
              square
              style={{ height: 80, width: 70 }}
              source={{
                uri: "https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/raw/react-navigation/img/logo.png"
              }}
            />
          </Image>
          <List
            dataArray={routes}
            renderRow={data => {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  button
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile")}>
                  <Text>{data}</Text>
                </ListItem>
              );
            }}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: route.RouteName is undefined. Please share your code.

Comment: It would be better to edit your post and place that code there than in a comment - this would make it more readable.